# ResourceBundle properties don't bring messages according to selected language

Tags: java, jsf, internationalization, cdi, javabeans

I'm translating backend messages into my app.

I wrote a BundleProducer for that:

```
package util;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Model;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import java.util.PropertyResourceBundle;

@Model
public class BundleProducer{
    @Produces
    public PropertyResourceBundle getBundle() {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return facesContext.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext, "#{msg}", PropertyResourceBundle.class);
    }
}
```

Inject:

```
protected transient @Inject
PropertyResourceBundle msg;
```

Call:

```
FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg.getString("inactive-user"), "");
fc.addMessage(null, m);
```

The code works perfectly for `@RequestScoped` and `@ConversationScoped` beans; the properties messages display translated according to the selected language.

But when I call `msg.getString("some-property")` in a `@SessionScoped` or `@ApplicationScoped` bean, it displays the message, but in default app's language (Spanish), ignoring the selected one (English, for example).

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of *selected language*?

The `FacesContext` can determine the current locale based on the current request, but in session scope or application scope, there is no current request.

It might help to replace your `@Produces` by `@Produces @RequestScoped`. At the moment, you get the default scope which is `@Dependent`.

Comment: The selected language is any language _that's not_ app's default. I followed your advice and added `@RequestScoped` to the producer. However, is not working, it throws UnproxyableResolutionException.